# How to resolve bazel "undeclared inclusion(s)" error?

Tags: c++, bazel

I'm new to bazel, and I'm getting a failure to build my C++ package with

> ERROR: /path/to/package/BUILD:linenumber:1 undeclared inclusion(s) in rule '//path/to/package:name':
> this rule is missing dependency declarations for the following files included by 'path/to/package/source_file.cpp'

...followed by a list of header files in a different directory.  These files are not part of the package that is being built, but are being pulled in from elsewhere.

**My question is how to properly add the declaration to the BUILD file to resolve the error?**

According to the online Bazel docu [here](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/be/c-cpp.html#cc_library) I should add each header to the **srcs** list.  (To be clear, these are headers that are used internally by the library I'm building and ***not*** part of the public interface, so they don't belong in **hdrs**.)   But If I try that,

```
  srcs = [ ..., "path/to/dependent/headers/header.h",]
```

I get an error message

> ERROR: ... crosses boundary of subpackage ... (perhaps you meant to
> put the colon here: ...?)

because the directory with the headers isn't a Bazel package.

If I try changing the final / to a colon as that error message suggests,

```
  srcs = [ ..., "path/to/dependent/headers:header.h",]
```

then

> ERROR: ... target names may not contain ':'.

The Bazel C++ tutorial [here](https://bazel.build/tutorials/cpp-use-cases#add-include-paths), in the section "Adding include paths" says that external include directories should be declared via **copts**:

```
cc_library(
    name = "some_lib",
    srcs = ["some_lib.cc"],
    hdrs = ["some_lib.h"],
    copts = ["-Ithird_party/some_lib"],
)
```

But adding that -I flag does ***not*** git rid of the "undeclared inclusion(s)" error!

```
$ bazel version
Build label: 0.4.3
Build target: bazel-out/local-fastbuild/bin/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/bazel/BazelServer_deploy.jar
Build time: Thu Dec 22 12:31:25 2016 (1482409885)
Build timestamp: 1482409885
Build timestamp as int: 1482409885
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bazel wants you to depend on the headers (i.e., put them in `deps`). Basically, you should create a cc_library for those headers.  Putting headers in `hdrs` doesn't publicly expose them, it just exposes them to rules that depend on that library (which is exactly what you want).  So you'll have:

```
# third_party/some_lib/BUILD
cc_library(
    name = "headers",
    hdrs = glob(["*.h"]),
    visibility = ["//path/to/package:__pkg__"],
)
```

Note that you should replace //path/to/package with your actual target's package, but the `__pkg__` above is literal: that's how you indicate "visible to that package".  Then no other packages can access those headers.

Then add `//third_party/some_lib:headers` in your target's `deps`.

The `copts` are just used to modify C++'s header search paths, not Bazel's. Bazel always assumes that you'll do `#include "path/relative/to/your/workspace/dir.h"`, but if you've got a source like:

```
#include "foo.h"
```

where `foo.h` is at third_party/some_lib/includes/foo.h, you could say `copts = ["-Ithird_party/some_lib/includes"]` to add that to C++'s header search path.

Comment: Thanks, @kristina.   So, the trick is I have to modify the third_party source tree to add a minimal Bazel BUILD file over there -- whether I "own" that tree or not.   It can't be done from inside the source tree for my package.

Comment: Sort of, you can add a BUILD file at `//third_party:BUILD` or `//:BUILD`, if you don't want to "pollute" a 3rd party source.

Answer (score 17):

I met a similar problem "undeclared inclusion(s) in rule", I solved it by removing the bazel cache files in "/root/.cache/bazel/".

Comment: Thanks, I haven't used it in a while and it was something in the cache...

Comment: Deleting everything from the Bazel cache resolved the issue for me that I had after upgrading Clang on Windows and using in in Bazel with --compiler=clang-cl.

Comment: Please keep in mind that removing Bazel's cache has a big timing cost overhead. The whole cache has to be constructed from the beginning (which will take some time to do it). I haven't tried `Elizebeth Kurian`'s answer. It might provide better performance.

Answer (score 3):

try out this, this worked for me

```
bazel clean --expunge
```

this command will clean up all disk and memory traces of a Bazel instance. reference : https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/user-manual.html

Comment: This answer needs more explanation.

Comment: This answer worked for me. I believe I was missing Xcode on macOS when I first ran bazel and that must have cached something? Not sure. Ran this, then re ran and it worked!

Comment: Usually this happens whenever you update Xcode and there's some change in the headers. Happened to me when I updated to Sonoma / Xcode 15.1