# "undeclared inclusion(s)" in bazel with headers in subdirectories

Tags: bazel

I'm trying to use ArduinoJson in a C++ bazel project. It's a header only library with headers in subdirectories under src. But I get an **undeclared inclusion(s)** error.

This is how the `//Third-Party/ArduinoJson` cc_library def looks like:

```
cc_library(
    name = "ArduinoJson",
    hdrs = glob(["5.12.0/src/**"]),
    includes = [
        "5.12.0/src",
        "5.12.0/src/ArduinoJson",
    ],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

The target that uses it (Serialization) **does** have `//Third-Party/ArduinoJson` in it's `deps`

Here is the error:

```
ERROR: /[...]/Serialization/BUILD:1:1: undeclared inclusion(s) in rule '//[...]/Serialization:Serialization':
this rule is missing dependency declarations for the following files included by '[...]/Serialization/JsonDeserializer.cpp':
  '[...]/Third-Party/ArduinoJson/5.12.0/src/ArduinoJson/Data/Encoding.hpp'
  '[...]/Third-Party/ArduinoJson/5.12.0/src/ArduinoJson/Serialization/FloatParts.hpp'
  '[...]/Third-Party/ArduinoJson/5.12.0/src/ArduinoJson/Polyfills/math.hpp'
  '[...]/Third-Party/ArduinoJson/5.12.0/src/ArduinoJson/TypeTraits/FloatTraits.hpp'
Target //[...]/Serialization:Serialization failed to build
```

Since it is only complaining about files in subdirectories of `src`, e.g. `src/Data/Encoding.hpp`, I'm guessing that might have something to do with it?

This is not a duplicate of ["How to resolve bazel “undeclared inclusion(s)” error?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43921911/how-to-resolve-bazel-undeclared-inclusions-error) since that one is solved by doing what I'm already doing with deps.

Comment: Using the `Third-Party/ArduinoJson/5.12.0/scripts/build-single-header.sh` script, it is possible to work around this problem. Keeping question open though as this is not a real solution.

Comment: I created a tiny repro workspace, but cannot reproduce what you observe. What compiler do you use? How do you include those affected headers ("" vs <>)? Could you set up a tiny repro that demonstrates the issue? It might even be reasonable to open a github issue for this if you believe this is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there are no BUILD files in the subdirectories of `Third-Party/ArduinoJson`, otherwise Bazel regards those as packages and the `glob` won't pick up files from them.

If you do have BUILD files in those subdirectories, you need to create `cc_library` rules in them, exporting the headers that you wanted in `//Third-Party/ArduinoJson:ArduinoJson`, and depending on these cc_libraries from ArduinoJson.

Comment: Nope, no BUILD file there.